# For Greenplum how to grant read only privileges of all tables of a database to user

Tags: privileges, greenplum

I tried

```
# grant select on all tables in schema public to tester;
ERROR: syntax error at or near "all"
LINE 1: grant select on all tables in schema public to tester;
```

my gp version is 5.22

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you look at these notes, which might help?
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91953/grant-access-to-all-tables-of-a-database

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum is Postgres:

`GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO tester;`

...but since it's public, they would have ready anyway :)